# Gedmo/Sluggable storing numbers instead of string

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, slug

I've been using the sluggable doctrine extension for quite a while, but suddenly it started to store numbers instead of the expected string. It looks like there is no string at the moment of creating the slug.

That's an excerpt of the file

```
<?php

namespace YourPower\EventBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

/**
 * YourPower\EventBundle\Entity\EventTag
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourPower\EventBundle\Entity\EventTagRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class EventTag
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */

private $id;

/**
 * @var tag
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $tag;

/**
 * @var string $url
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"tag"})
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false, unique=true)
 */
private $url = '';
```

I haven't done any changes to this file since ages... so I don't think that I messed something up. I checked the commit logs of the bundle and the doctrine extension but to no avail :-( Google couldn't help me neither.

Does anybody have a clue about what could be the reason for that new behaviour?

UPD: Going back to version 2.3.7 of DoctrineExtensions solved the issue... strange that no other people seem to be affected...

Comment: could you please add your findings/solution as an answer?

Comment: @nifr I will as soon as I have a definite solution

Answer (score 0):

The solutions seems to be to revert Gedmo/DoctrineExtensions to version 2.3.7.
Between 2.3.7 and 2.3.8 there has been some heavy refactoring of the Sluggable feature resulting in lost strings.

Yet, it's not clear to me why it does not seem to affect other users as there is no information available.